# Addressing different File in Different Directory 

Tags: asp.net, xml, jquery-ui, jquery

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
 url: "Administrator\Questions.xml",//folder Administrator   
success: parseXml
});



function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("Question").each(function()
  {  
    $('#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",$(this).find('Text').text()).
      text($(this).find('Text').text())); 
  });
}
```

1.
does not found xmlFile;

but if copy XMLFile To Root Project and url:Questions.xml then Found XMLFile

2.
when found file and add option to select

row 1: 'SPACE'

row 2: DATA

row 3:DATA

how remove 'space' in Row1

3.
how is Addressing different File in Different Directory by jquery and asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of url `Administrator\Questions.xml` use `Administrator/Questions.xml`. Backslashes are not used in URLs. Also, even if used, it would have to be `Administrator\\Questions.xml` - because of special meaning of backslash in javascript strings.
2. To remove 'SPACE' use this:

   ```
   function parseXml(xml)
   {
       $(xml).find("Question").each(function()
       {  
           var value = $(this).find('Text').text();

           if (value.toUpperCase() !== "SPACE")
               {
               $('#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').
                   append($("<option></option>").
                   attr("value", value).
                   text(value);
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. The type of directory separators used by ASP.NET is determined by underlying operating system. In Windows it's backslash.
   The type of separators used in URLs is forward slash. That's what jquery uses in its $.ajax function argument for urls.

Comment: tanks very useful . but sample for get file in different directory by jquery and asp